# Marionette: get single instance of a layout view

Tags: backbone.js, layout, singleton, marionette, regions

I am creating an application which has multiple views. Each view has got a left sidebar region and a main content region.

I have added two regions in my layout -> leftSidebarRegion and mainContentRegion. Now for each of these views the left sidebar content remains the same, but the mainContentRegion keeps on changing. This change in mainContentRegion is event driven.

I want to know how can I access my layout instance [created once in main controller of my module] so that leftSidebarRegion is not reloaded and I only change mainContentRegion.

Additional information: I have different view files for populating leftSidebarRegion and mainContentRegion.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the region from the layout object.

var layout = new Layout();

layout.mainContentRegion.show(new ViewYouWantToRender());

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think doing new Layout() will create a new instance of my layout so in this case I will have to re render leftSidebarRegion which I dont want to do unless it's not created previously.

Comment: Well once the layout is instantiated you don't have to create another instance. If you want to have the layout globally accessible just set it as a variable on the App object when instantiating it in your controller: App.myLayout = new Layout().

Comment: Or you could set it as a variable on a module, if you are using one.